# Wrapping an equation around a list

Tags: equations, align, enumerate

Is it possible to apply a single centered equation # to a list? I'm using aligned wrapped with equation in the first list but 1) it requires a fair amount of manual spacing to make it look right and 2) long items are misbehaving. Item (iii) is commented out, as it breaks the formatting and I can't seem to reign it in. The enumerate in the 2nd list is formatted perfectly but lacks an equation number. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

```
\documentclass[12pt, leqno]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm} 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hspace*{#1}}  
\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand\dvd[2]{#1\!\mid\!#2}

\begin{document}
\noindent Using the equation env, this list is numbered and does what I want, except I'm struggling with
how to treat long lines (as in item (iii) which is commented out).
\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
      &\text{(i) }   \enspace \text{If $a>b$ then $a+c > b+c$ for every $c \in D$.} \blank{15mm}  \\
      &\text{(ii) }  \>       \text{If $a>b$ and $c>0$, then $ac>bc$.}  \\ 
 %      &\text{(iii) }          \text{If If $a \neq 0$ and $\dvd{d}{a}$, then $\abs{d} \leq \abs{a}$. Moreover, if $a \neq 0$, and $d \neq \pm a$, then $\abs{d} < \abs{a}$. } \\
      &\text{(iv) }           \text{If $a>b$ and $b>c$, then $a>c$.}    \\ 
      &\text{(v) }   \>       \text{If $a \neq 0$, then $a^2 > 0$.}     \\ 
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\noindent Using the enumerate env handles the items perfectly with the desired formatting. I just
don't get a centered equation number.

\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*, label=(\roman*),widest=viii, align=left, noitemsep]
   \item If $a>b$ then $a+c > b+c$ for every $c \in D$.
   \item If $a>b$ and $c>0$, then $ac>bc$.
   \item If If $a \neq 0$ and $\dvd{d}{a}$, then $\abs{d} \leq \abs{a}$. Moreover, if $a \neq 0$, and $d \neq \pm a$, then $\abs{d} < \abs{a}$.
   \item If $a>b$ and $b>c$, then $a>c$.
   \item If $a \neq 0$, then $a^2 > 0$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Rather than define `\dvd` as `\newcommand\dvd[2]{#1\!\mid\!#2}`, it may be more natural (to me at least...) to define it as `\newcommand\dvd[2]{#1\mkern2mu\vert\mkern2mu #2}`. (`\mid` is defined, essentially, as `\mkern5mu\vert\mkern5mu`; `\!` is equivalent to `\mkern-3mu`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the enumerate environment in a `\parbox`. B.t.w., I think the item numbers look better when right-aligned here. I also took the opportunity to re-define  `\abs` with `mathtools (so it can have variable size):

```
\documentclass[12pt, leqno]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hspace*{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
%\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand\dvd[2]{#1\!\mid\!#2}

\begin{document}

\noindent Using the enumerate env handles the items perfectly with the desired formatting. I just get a centred equation number.
\begin{equation}
  \parbox{0.9\linewidth}{\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*, label=(\roman*),widest=viii, labelsep=0.8em, noitemsep]
    \item If $a>b$ then $a+c > b+c$ for every $c \in D$.
    \item If $a>b$ and $c>0$, then $ac>bc$.
    \item If If $a \neq 0$ and $\dvd{d}{a}$, then $\abs{d} \leq \abs{a}$. Moreover, if $a \neq 0$, and $d \neq \pm a$, then $\abs{d} < \abs{a}$.
    \item If $a>b$ and $b>c$, then $a>c$.
    \item If $a \neq 0$, then $a^2 > 0$.
    \end{enumerate}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: more space than necessary between paragraph text and the list.  to get better spacing, don't leave a blank line there in the input.

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot the blank line in the O.P. on inserting `equation`. Corrected. Thanks for pointing it.